# Why is redux-form throwing an error?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am trying to implement redux-form but I am coming across an error and can't seem to fix it or find the correct solution. 
Error: `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.`

```
import { Form, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';


    LocationInput({input, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom}) {
    return (
      <div>
        <input placeholder="Location..." type="text" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Form name="locationInput" component={this.LocationInput} />
    )

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a form component and export the formComponent using redux-form decorator

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'formName'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(formComponent)
```

Comment: @ErikR. Point noted. But he does need to decorate it with `reduxForm()`, right?

Comment: Yes. The main problem is that he's using [`Form`](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Form.md/) when he shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `Form`, unless you are doing some fancy submission via action dispatching. Look more at the examples.

You need to define a form component, decorate it with `reduxForm()`, and then put some `<Field>` elements inside it.